# Creating shapefile from Excel file in QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, convert, csv, excel, qgis-2.6

I am using QGIS 2.6.1 and have worked in an Excel file database (which was actually converted from a Shapefile). I have managed to convert it as CSV file and load it into QGIS (displays data fine) but I have trouble to convert it to a shapefile.

I can view it but I can´t add or alter data in this file. I think I have to save it as a database.

Any clues how to convert the xlsl-data to a database and finally to a shapefile?

Answer (score 6):

You can save the csv layer as shapefile to edit the data.

Therefore right click the added csv layer in the layer menue and select `Save as...`.

Following dialog will open:

[image]

Now you can save your csv as shapefile. The resulting shapefile is editable.

Comment: I tried this multiple times but I alwas get the (German) error code  "Export in Vektordatei schlug fehl.
Fehler: Layererzeugung schlug fehl (OGR-Fehler: Failed to open Shapefile `test.shp'".
)

Comment: It fails to open the file you want to save to?

Comment: Yes but I am currently working on it.  I just managed to get a copy saved as shp but my main file is still complaining. But I am positive that I will get it done. Probably, I have to rename or close the main file. Will try out. Thanks.

Comment: Probably you still have the layer in edit mode. Try to close all edit modes and try to save again.

Comment: @DarthFreder - Awesome! Please accept this answer (click the faded tick on the left-hand side) to close off this question.