# Exporting CSV to shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv

I have a simple CSV of {lat,lon,text} and I want to export it as a WGS84 Shapefile.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can't "comment" here yet, but have you tried what's discussed [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136838/qgis-2-6-how-to-create-a-shapefile-from-an-excel-file)? Made sure you're out of any "edit mode" etc.?

Comment: I have suggested that it is the duplicate of different question but reading both http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136838/creating-shapefile-from-excel-file-in-qgis and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158985/exporting-csv-file-as-shp-in-qgis/159428#159428 and this question again it is in my point of view not duplicate of any of these two. The first one is pretty close but it is missing the information on how to load csv including geometry into QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open as a text file layer (comma button on the right side panel)
2. Set X,Y axis as long, lat
3. Right click on the layer save as
4. Set coordinate system CRS to WGS84
5. Set format to ESRI Shape file